# PHP cannot edit .txt file

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest, file-put-contents

I am new at using PHP. I code a program by JavaScript (in html file) and use XMLHttpRequest() to send some value to php file and then I want this php file to overwrite something in txt file, but it didn't change anything in the txt file. I don't know why.

**I updated my code**

main.html:

```
<html>
    <label class="switch">
       <input id="switch" onclick="on_off()" type="checkbox">
       <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function on_off(){
       var switchStatus = "false";
       var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
       if ($('#switch').is(':checked')) {
          switchStatus = "true";
          xmlhttp.open("GET","../static/fwrite.php?q="+switchStatus,true);
          xmlhttp.send();
          console.log("save true")
       }
       else {
          switchStatus = "false";
          xmlhttp.open("GET","../static/fwrite.php?q="+switchStatus,true);
          xmlhttp.send();
          console.log("save false")
       }
    }
</script>
```

fwrite.php:

```
<?php

   $q=$_REQUEST["q"];
   file_put_contents("../static/temp.txt", $q);

?>
```

temp.txt: (default is false.)

```
false
```

When I rendered this program, it has no error, but temp.txt didn't change anything.
Could anyone tell me how to solve it?

Comment: Please provide the html

Comment: Check the permissions on the file, make sure the webserver userid has permission to write it.

Comment: @Mulli Sorry, I updated my code already.

Comment: Add ```error_log() ```  in your fwrite.php (bad name by the way) and see if it is called and if ```file_put_contents``` is successful

Comment: @Mulli It showed an error like this "POST http://127.0.0.1/static/fwrite.php?q=true   405 (METHOD NOT ALLOWED) " Could you tell me how to solve that one?

Comment: @Barmar maybe the problem will be as you said, but I don't know how to solve it.